# Как пробросить порты в докер контейнер который работает с --network host

Tags: docker

Есть база данных, которая работает не в контейнере в локальной сети. Чтобы к ней подключиться я запускаю контейнер с параметром **--network host**, но при этом параметре не пробрасываются порты в контейнер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно, потому что при таких настройках, порты открываются сразу на хосте - смысл проброса просто отпадает.